# Java: <E extends Comparable <E>>

Tags: java, arrays, generics

So this program is attempted to take a command line argument like the following:

```
S 4 1 2 3 4 4
```

`args[0]` is the array type

`args[1]` is the array length

`args[2...]` are the values in the array

`args[length-1]` is a key that will be used in a linear search

```
public class whatTheFoo{

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static <E> void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)System.out.print(args[i]);
        System.out.println();

        int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        E[] array = (E[])new Object[arraySize];
        E key = null;

        if (args[0].matches("I|i")) {
            for (int i = 2; i < args.length-1; i++) {
                array[i-2]=(E)new Integer(args[i]);
                System.out.println(array[i-2]);
            }
            key = (E) new Integer(args[args.length-1]);
            System.out.println("Key is: " + key);
        } 

    ...

        if(linearSearch(array, key)<0)
            System.out.println("Didnt find it");
        else 
            System.out.println("Found it at index: "+(linearSearch(array, key)-1));
    }

    public static <E> int linearSearch(E[]array,E key) {
        int index=-1;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            if(array[i].equals(key)){
                index = (int) array[i];
            }
        }
        return index;
    }
}
```

This works, but when I change the linearSearch method to:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int linearSearch(E[]array,E key)
```

I get the error message:

```
The method linearSearch(E[], E extends Comparable<E>) in the type Prog7b is not applicable for the arguments (E[], E)
```

but if I change main to:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void main(String[] args) {
```

I get:

```
 Exception in thread "main" I412344java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
at whatTheFoo.main(whatTheFoo.java:10)
```

The method has been directed to include in the method:

```
<E extends Comparable<E>>.
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks for reading.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For those that may be curious, this is the end result of all the help supplied. Thanks again!

```
public class Prog7b {

//  @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args[0].matches("I|i")) {
            Integer[] array = new Integer[Integer.parseInt(args[1])];
            for (int i = 2; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
                array[i - 2] = new Integer(args[i]);
            }
            Integer key = new Integer(args[args.length - 1]);
            if (linearSearch(array, key) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Didnt find it");
            } else
                System.out.println("Found it at index: " + (linearSearch(array, key) - 1));
            System.out.println("The max of the array is: " + max(array));
            print(array);
        } else if (args[0].matches("S|s")) {
            String[] array = new String[Integer.parseInt(args[1])];
            for (int i = 2; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
                array[i - 2] = new String(args[i]);
            }
            String key = new String(args[args.length - 1]);
            if (linearSearch(array, key) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Didnt find it");
            } else
                System.out.println("Found it at index: " + (linearSearch(array, key) - 1));
            System.out.println("The max of the array is: " + max(array));
            print(array);
        } else {
            Double[] array = new Double[Integer.parseInt(args[1])];
            for (int i = 2; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
                array[i - 2] = new Double(args[i]);
            }
            Double key = new Double(args[args.length - 1]);
            if (linearSearch(array, key) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Didnt find it");
            } else
                System.out.println("Found it at index: " + (linearSearch(array, key) - 1));
            System.out.println("The max of the array is: " + max(array));
            print(array);
        }
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int linearSearch(E[] array, E key) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            index++;
            if (array[i].equals(key)) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(E[] list) {
        E max = list[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (max.compareTo(list[i]) < 0) {
                max = list[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    private static <E> void print(E[] list) {
        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++)
            System.out.print(list[i] + ", ");
        System.out.print(list[list.length - 1] + "]\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to type erasure, `E` is being replaced by `Object` at runtime.  I'm not sure what type you expect `E` to be.

Comment: Why do you even need `E` ?

Comment: I am under the assumption I need E because the type of array is being decided in the command line argument and is not hardcoded. For the linear search, it is supposed to take in any array, whether it be int, string, or double and check for the key value.

Comment: You can keep `E` on the searching method, but it's not needed in your main method, as any object can be passed to the searching method.

Comment: Generics are compile-time only so they don't do you any good here, except maybe in the linear search method. By the way, `[Ljava.lang.Object;` and `[Ljava.lang.Comparable;` are array types, `Object[]` and `Comparable[]` respectively. So the message is telling you that your program tried to cast an `Object[]` to a `Comparable[]`.

Comment: And all of that would work when you just use Object and Object[] in the signature of the search method. But I agree, the core point of your question is interesting. I am guessing it is due to the fact that you use generic types on the method level. I will look into this later on...

Comment: Starting with a null array and then setting the null array as either an int, string or double within the conditional statements is what did it. Im sure there are many things I am doing in this spaghetti mess of a  program, but Im learning. Thanks to all who helped!

Comment: And hint: suppressing those warnings is super bad practice. And never put more information into comments!

Comment: @GhostCat Well, they appear to need to use `Comparable` in the search method so they do need to use generics for that (or raw types...). This isn't stated in the question, though.

Comment: @GhostCat Since this is a homework assignment, the teacher actually has that in the code provided, so I just went with it. I look forward to when I can code well enough to not need the statement.

Comment: The whole code is weird. It would not surprise me when the suppressed warnings warn exactly about that part that gives the exception.

Comment: I have a rather uneasy feeling about your teacher then.

Comment: @GhostCat I have a friend that programs for some big companies who says the exact same thing.... heh.

Comment: `Object[]` is-not-a `Comparable[]`, which caused the exception.  It is always messy to have generics + array... Can you just switch to use an `ArrayList` instead?

Comment: @AdrianShum not in this case, unfortunately. For the previous application I worked on, an arraylist was used. This had to be an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `main` is supposed to be generic. (The `<E>` part in the method declaration declares a type variable, which makes it generic.) If `main` is really supposed to be generic, then you need to talk to your teacher because they are doing something weird and we can't really guess about it.

Generics are a compile-time only concept. Basically the idea is that you have some code which is actually somewhat agnostic about particular types, but still need some kind of abstract information about it.

For example, suppose we had some method that checks if an object is null:

```
Object requireNonNull(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

This is fine. We can pass any sort of object to the method. (`Integer`, `String`, whatever.) But what if we wanted to assign the return value directly?

We want to be able to do this:

```
String mightBeNull = ...;
String definatelyNotNull = requireNonNull(mightBeNull);
```

This makes our validation code neater. (Maybe instead of checking for null, our validation is actually about 10 lines long and we don't want to repeat it all the time.)

Well, as it stands, we can't, because we will get a compile-time error for trying to assign an `Object` to a `String`.

Generics let us do this, though:

```
<T> T requireNonNull(T obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

The type parameter `<T>` says that we declare a sort of temporary type. We don't care about what it actually is, but we can say that the method returns whatever we pass to it. Whatever type `obj` is at the point that we call `requireNonNull`, the method returns that type to the caller.

So now we can do this:

```
String  s = requireNonNull("");
Integer i = requireNonNull(10);
Float   f = requireNonNull(2f);
```

And so on.

[`requireNonNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) is actually a real method and that is how it works.

The point, though, is that generics let you write very general API which gets called by non-generic code.

For your assignment it looks like you're supposed to write a generic method `linearSearch` with a bounded type parameter `<E extends Comparable<E>>` (essentially meaning that whatever array type you pass to `linearSearch`, it has to be some subtype of `Comparable`). Then you're probably supposed to pass it different types of arrays in `main`, like `Integer[]`, `String[]`, etc. Your `main` method won't be generic. You'll just have an `if...else if` chain for each type that `args[0]` requires.

Comment: I changed the conditions so they created regular arrays, but get an error when I try to pass the arrays to the methods: The method linearSearch(E[], E) in the type Prog7b is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int)

Comment: You have to use the boxed classes (`Integer[]`, `Boolean[]`, `Character[]`, etc.) if you want to pass them to generic code. You can e.g. autobox from `int` to `Integer`, but not for arrays like `int[]` to `Integer[]`.

Comment: Added the full revised code for anyone that may wonder something similar in the future. Good practice or is it something not typically done?

Comment: It's fine. It would only be bad if it change the question to the point of making it confusing for future readers or made the answers no longer relevant. (For example sometimes people will actually remove the code that didn't work altogether and replace it with code that did, so that you can't understand what the question was originally about. Something like that is bad.) You could post your finished code as an answer, if you wanted, but I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Got it. So what I did to the original post should be ok. Future readers can see the old code and how it was revised. Thanks for the insight! It truly helped.